# Trouble understanding the alignment of epipoles with an axe

Tags: computer-vision, vision, projective-geometry

This question arose when I was reading [this paper](http://twd20g.blogspot.fr/2013/08/an-iterative-5-pt-algorithm-for-fast.html). The goal is the estimation of the relative pose of two cameras **C<sub>1</sub>** and **C<sub>2</sub>**, given five point correspondences.

The projective planes are considered as unit spheres, and the global coordinate system is chosen such that the **Z<sub>G</sub>** axis joins the camera centers. The problem is solved if we can find two matrices **R<sub>1</sub>** and **R<sub>2</sub>**, respectively mapping the internal coordinate systems of **C<sub>1</sub>** and **C<sub>2</sub>** to the global system described previously (to me, it sounds that these matrices will just align the **Z<sub>c_1</sub>** and **Z<sub>c_2</sub>** axes of the cameras with the global **Z<sub>G</sub>** axis).

These matrices are computed in an iterative manner, and at each iteration, all point correspondences **(v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>)** are updated via a rotation, becoming **(R<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub>,R<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>)**.

So far, everything makes sense. But later, the authors state that these rotations change the direction of the epipoles (I assume relative to the camera Z axes), and that *"by rotating the unit spheres such that the z-axis **Z<sub>G</sub>** is aligned with the epipoles, i.e. **Z<sub>G</sub>=R<sub>1</sub>e<sub>1</sub>=R<sub>2</sub>e<sub>2</sub>** the rotated point correspondences **(v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>)** become coplanar with the epipoles **e<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>**".*

To me, the **Z<sub>G</sub>** axis, being the baseline, is always aligned with the epipoles, and a rotated epipole **Re** is no longer an epipole, since it moves away from the baseline. But the quotation above implies that there are configurations in which the epipoles are not aligned... As you can see, I'm completely confused... please help me understand what the author means by that.